# want to generate more than one random number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to use user input to generate a number of random numbers. this is my code so far, only getting one random number to show.

```
class NumGenerator extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    dice:2,
    max: 6
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({ number: this.generateNumber(this.state.max)})
}

diceChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ dice: event.target.value})
  }
 
maxChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ max: event.target.value})
}


generateNumber = (max) => {
  return  Math.floor(Math.random()*(max)+1)
}

getInputs = () => {
    this.setState({
      number: this.generateNumber(this.state.max)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change number state to an array type and in your code where you are setting number state, do something like this

```
const numbers = [...this.state.numbers];
numbers.push(generaterandomnumber());
this.setState({ numbers}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @Pradhumn Sharma is right, I believe what you are misunderstanding is that every time you add a new object `{ number: value }` to the state, the state overrides the previous value (comparing by key), then it won't add an extra pair `{ number: value }`. That's why you are getting only one random number to show, which should be the last created.

Comment: Obviously, this is how the state works, but we can use the previous state and set a new state in concatenation with it. Something like this
const random_number = generatenumber();
this.setState((prevState) => {
  numbers: [...prevState.numbers, random_number]
});

Comment: Yeah, totally. I meant to add up something to @Rolo, not you, your answer is right.